# Can you use Greenguard for an attic access insulation cover

Tags: insulation, attic

My understanding is that *Greenguard* needs to be covered by a thermal barrier like drywall when you install it.  Is there a way to use a leftover piece of *Greenguard* to make an attic access insulation cover safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure can. The Green XPS foam board is very versatile, but it should never be used to walk on. However, it can work just fine in multiple layers as a ceiling access drop-in panel. Any other use for floor or wall access must be inserted into a frame that is structurally sound for the application.

Comment: do i need to add a thermal barrier to it if i use it that way?  i don't intend on walking on it

Comment: No, that would suffice as both your insulation and removable panel. You should still glue or tape 2 or 3 layers together for better insulation and durability.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can. Greenboard IS drywall, but it has a thicker paper shell that's coated with wax to make it water resistant. It's typically used in high-humidty locations such as bathrooms. However, it's not water-proof and shouldn't be used where direct exposure to water is expected (such as a shower stall).

Comment: I think OP was asking about green foam board insulation (XPS).  I know he said Greenboard, but reading the rest of his question he's asking about insulating an attic access hatch.

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking as I started reading the question. I'll give it a +1. Heck, there is _some_ amount of insulating property in greenboard/drywall, so maybe this _is_ what the OP means...

Comment: Yeah, I mean greenguard, not greenboard.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Title changed to remove "greenboard"